# How do I set a person or group field via the API V1 using Rails with Faraday?

Tags: rest, api, person-or-group

I've seen several similar questions and the crux of the answer seems to be that I should add "Id" to the field name and pass the user's id. Here for instance:

[How to update "Person or Group" column in SharePoint List using REST API](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/273036/how-to-update-person-or-group-column-in-sharepoint-list-using-rest-api)

But when try that I get an error saying the field is not recognized. The field name in this case is Agent.

`@status=400 @reason_phrase="Bad Request" @response_body="{\"error\":{\"code\":\"invalidRequest\",\"message\":\"Field 'AgentId' is not recognized\"`

All of the other field types update as expected, including single line of text, choice, and date/time, but this person/group field has me banging my head against the wall. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You have to use the internal name of columns. Can you confirm if you are using correct internal name?

Comment: I can confirm that I am using the correct internal name. I'm adding the 'Id" to it but the internal name is Agent. If I remove the 'Id' and just use Agent, no errors are returned but the corresponding field is not set.